# How to fix SSL cert verification checks on httplib.HTTPSConnection?

Tags: python

Any ideas what to fix and secure library to use for fixing SSL cert verification checks on httplib.HTTPSConnection https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OSSN/OSSN-0033 ? Thanks

```
Test results:
     >> Issue: [B309:blacklist] Use of HTTPSConnection does not 
    provide security, see https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OSSN/OSSN-0033
      Severity: Medium   Confidence: High
 def _get_connection(self):            
     return httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.hostname, timeout=120)

      --------------------------------------------------
       >> Issue: [B309:blacklist] Use of HTTPSConnection 
        does not provide security, 
            see https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OSSN/OSSN-0033
          Severity: Medium   Confidence: High
      conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(pa.hostname)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade your library versions

This issue seems to have been fixed back in 2014 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/). Current versions of HTTPSConnection do check SSL certificate validity.

Using the latest stable 2.7.x or 3.x Python should be sufficient for that. If you *are* using a recent version of Python but that test is simply flagging all mentions of HTTPSConnection - well, then that test is outdated and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a release note that says this issue has been fixed?